# Generate Rails code from Swagger

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rest, sinatra, swagger

Is it possible to generate the server code of a Rails app thanks to a Swagger YAML file?

I saw it was possible for a Ruby client, thanks to https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-codegen.

I give it a try with this command:

```
swagger-codegen generate -i http://petstore.swagger.io/v2/swagger.json -l ruby -o /tmp/test/
```

and it's pretty amazing. Is there something similar for the code of a Rails backend?

Answer (score 3):

Currently, Swagger-Codegen does not provide a generator for Rails app. The closest is the [Ruby Sinatra](https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-codegen#ruby-sinatra) server stub generator.

If you've time to contribute a generator for Rails app, ["How to add a generator for a new language or framework"](https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-codegen/wiki/How-to-add-a-generator-for-a-new-language-or-framework)
 is a good starting point.

UPDATE: The `ruby-on-rails` generator has been added. In addition, about 50 top contributors and template creators of Swagger Codegen decided to fork Swagger Codegen to maintain a community-driven version called [OpenAPI Generator](https://github.com/OpenAPITools/openapi-generator) on May 2018. Please refer to the [Q&A](https://github.com/OpenAPITools/openapi-generator/blob/master/docs/qna.md) for more information.